# Get maxdate less than the current date

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a service tax calculation in my page.For that i have to get the current service tax.

Service Tax table is as follows

```
 Date                          Percentage

2015-10-01 00:00:00.000          14

2015-11-15 06:12:31.687          14.5
```

Say if the current date is `less than 2015-11-15` I will get the the value of `percentage` as `14` and if the current date is `equal to or greater than 2015-11-15` i should get the value of `percentage` as `14.5` .

How can I implement this using `Linq`??

Comment: I don't really get your question, you have both records in your table and you need to fetch one or the other depending on time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all taxes which are lower and fetch only first after sorting:

```
Taxes
    .Where(t => t.Date < DateTime.Now)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
    .First()
```

Comment: This makes him fetch all records, even the ones he doesn't need... Better to compare the date on the database

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compare a date, it's better to do so on the database to prevent fetching useless data. To do this you can make use of `System.Data.Entity` namespace to access some functions:

```
db.Taxes.Where(t => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Date) 
                    < DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dateParameter)).FirstOrDefault();
```

`System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(Datetime)` trims the time part of a `DateTime` value on the database.